# OpenAL Soft CMake missing packages

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, openal, openal-soft

As I am trying to build OpenAL Soft in Ubuntu using CMake, it says it is missing packages. Am I missing an installation step? Or do I need to figure out which package names I need to install exactly?

I am seeing the following output:

```
sudo cmake ..
-- Could NOT find AudioIO (missing: AUDIOIO_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find OpenSL (missing: OPENSL_LIBRARY OPENSL_INCLUDE_DIR OPENSL_ANDROID_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Checking for module 'libavcodec'
--   No package 'libavcodec' found
-- Checking for module 'libavformat'
--   No package 'libavformat' found
-- Checking for module 'libavdevice'
--   No package 'libavdevice' found
-- Checking for module 'libavutil'
--   No package 'libavutil' found
-- Checking for module 'libswscale'
--   No package 'libswscale' found
-- Checking for module 'libswresample'
--   No package 'libswresample' found
-- Checking for module 'libpostproc'
--   No package 'libpostproc' found
-- Could NOT find FFmpeg (missing: FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIRS AVFORMAT_LIBRARIES AVFORMAT_INCLUDE_DIRS AVCODEC_LIBRARIES AVCODEC_INCLUDE_DIRS AVUTIL_LIBRARIES AVUTIL_INCLUDE_DIRS SWSCALE_LIBRARIES SWSCALE_INCLUDE_DIRS SWRESAMPLE_LIBRARIES SWRESAMPLE_INCLUDE_DIRS)
--
Building OpenAL with support for the following backends:
     ALSA, OSS, SndIO (linked), PortAudio, PulseAudio, JACK, WaveFile, Null

Building with support for CPU extensions:
    Default, SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSE4.1

-- Embedding HRTF datasets

-- Installing library and headers
-- Installing sample configuration
-- Installing HRTF data files
-- Installing AmbDec presets
--
-- Could NOT find MySOFA (missing: MYSOFA_LIBRARY MYSOFA_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Building utility programs
-- Building configuration program
--
-- Building example programs
-- Building SndFile example programs
-- Building SDL example programs
--
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /download/openal-soft-1.21.1/build
```

Comment: According to the output, the configuration step is successful. So it seems given missed libraries are optional. Have you tried to build the project after that? You may also install these libraries: it shouldn't be difficult to find Ubuntu packages for them. In that case make sure to install `-dev` variants of these packages.

Comment: Thank you. Building as indeed successful. I was just surprised at the amount of dependencies not automatically found when all instructions are running `cmake ..`. I guess it should work, once I finished my pulseaudio issues

Comment: I ended up using the binaries instead of the source